# weekly query grouping visual basic ms access

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access, grouping

I need some help on how to group my data into weekly reports. I have asked for a monthly and yearly a month ago but I can't figure out how to do the weekly reports in the same style.

I don't have any idea too what output is good to show a weekly report, but maybe like this?

```
Week_Sold           Total_Earnings
January 1 2013           1
January 8 2013           5
```

Or like this?

```
Week_Sold            Total_Earnings
January 1st Week          5
January 2nd Week          8
```

Or like this?

```
Week_Sold            Total_Earnings
January 1-7               5
January 8-15              8
```

I have no idea what to do on this weekly so can someone recommend me a good weekly report format?

btw, my grouping is the same as the answer on this one [Yearly, monthly grouping Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886494/yearly-monthly-grouping-visual-basic) so please try to make the procedures close to this since im no good on Microsoft Access or Visual Basic.

Comment: Are the weekly reports for your usage or someone else's? If they're for your usage - then use whatever suits you best!! Personally I think the first format is the least ambiguous and least complicated but this is your report not mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 Format([YourDateColumn], "ww")
```

?

This should give you the weeknumber in ISO standard. There are also some additional switches; you should find those easily in VBA.